# Create Left Arrow with CSS before & after pseudo elements

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

I have created a right arrow.

How do I flip this to have a 2nd left arrow?

http://jsfiddle.net/n0rxtr48/

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:before, a:after {
    border-right: 2px solid;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    -moz-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(135deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
}

a:after {
    margin-top: -1px;
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

a:hover, a:focus,
a:hover:before, a:hover:after,
a:focus:before, a:focus:after {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a class="arrow"></a>
```

Comment: Why don't you just use font-awesome's chevron's ?

Comment: @robin Font awesome is not actually awesome. Font icons don't work in Opera Mini and are bad for accessibility. Today, icons should use SVG. This CSS arrow however, is excellent to have a visual arrow on a link without extra markup, while having screen readers ignore (not speak) the arrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can rotate the arrow 180deg like this :

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 10px 15px 10px 10px;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.left{
  transform:rotate(180deg);
}

a:before, a:after {
    border-right: 2px solid;
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    margin-top: -6px;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(135deg);
    right: 10px;
    top: 50%;
    width: 0;
}

a:after {
    margin-top: -1px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}

a:hover, a:focus,
a:hover:before, a:hover:after,
a:focus:before, a:focus:after {
    color: #000;
}
```

```html
<a class="arrow"></a>
<a class="arrow left"></a>
```

You can also achieve the same output with `scaley(-1)` instead of rotate.

Also there are way simpler ways to make this arrow, you might want to check this post with a great list of arrows like this one : [How to Make A Fancy Arrow Using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492191/how-to-make-a-fancy-arrow-using-css)

Answer (score 2):

Tranform CSS property does not work with a lot of devices. I would suggest that you use **Unicode symbols**.

Here is a list of arrows : http://unicode-table.com/en/sets/arrows-symbols/

Answer (score 1):

alternatively you can use borders

```css
:root{text-align: center}
a{width: 10px; height: 10px; position: relative}
a:before, a:after {
    color: black;
    border-right: 2px solid currentcolor;
    border-bottom: 2px solid currentcolor;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px
}

a:before{
    left: -16px;
    transform: rotate(135deg)
}
a:after{
    right: -16px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg)
}
```

```html
<a></a>
```