# Getting a particular shape using css only

Tags: css, css-shapes

[image: Desired image]
This is the desired shape intended to be achieved using CSS only.
I think it can be done using borders CSS property, but could not make it happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is:

http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/a0uogod0/

```
#arrow {
border-right:30px solid black;
border-bottom:30px solid black;
width:100px;
height:100px;
transform: rotate(-45deg);
margin-top:40px;
}
```

> JSFiddle accredited to user j08691 from [How to Make A Fancy Arrow Using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27492191/how-to-make-a-fancy-arrow-using-css)