# HTML & CSS - how to draw flow arrows

Tags: html, css

Please find attached image, there is a flow arrow which is the first field to second marked as red, can anyone help me out, how can I achieve it by using pure css

[image]

Comment: That's almost interesting, we require some code provide a [mcve], please.

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this:
[example1](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/tLtnfcdt/)
[example2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27492688/4571681)

```css
body{
  font-size: 25px; /* Change font and  see the magic! */
  color: #f07;     /* Change color and see the magic! */
} 

/* RESPONSIVE ARROWS */
[class^=arr-]{
  border:       solid currentColor;
  border-width: 0 .2em .2em 0;
  display:      inline-block;
  padding:      .20em;
}
.arr-right {transform:rotate(-45deg);  -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);}
.arr-left  {transform:rotate(135deg);  -webkit-transform:rotate(135deg);}
.arr-up    {transform:rotate(-135deg); -webkit-transform:rotate(-135deg);}
.arr-down  {transform:rotate(45deg);   -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);}
```

```html
This is <i class="arr-right"></i> .arr-right<br>
This is <i class="arr-left"></i> .arr-left<br>
This is <i class="arr-up"></i> .arr-up<br>
This is <i class="arr-down"></i> .arr-down
```